# Simple GUI for Oracle/SQLPlus Password Reset/Unlock

Tags: sql, oracle, sqlplus

We have a lab system that uses Oracle as the backend database. Currently user account unlocks and password resets are done via 2nd line technicians, using the SQL*Plus commandline. We'd like to left-shift this process to service desk. However, we don't want them to have access to the commandline, as it could be dangerous if the wrong command is entered.

I'd like to know if anyone has already written a simple GUI that would allow user's accounts to be unlocked (`ALTER USER “userid” ACCOUNT UNLOCK;`) or passwords reset (`ALTER USER “userid” IDENTIFIED BY password;`).

If a GUI doesn't already exist, what would be required to create one? I have some experience with Visual Studio, so I'm thinking 3 Windows forms. The first/main form would be simple, 2 text boxes, username & password, and 2 buttons, unlock & reset (which would send the username/password along with 1 of the 2 commands above). There would be a menu at the top, login, connection settings, and exit. Exit is self explanitory. Login would open  another form for the service desk analysts to login with their super user IDs. Connection settings would open a form to create/edit the oracle DB connection, or it would open the default Windows ODBC connection box, and allow you to create/edit a connection there.

Comment: i would make an oracle application express (APEX) app - you'd have a webpage, with your supports folks logging in, and they'd have the screens exactly like you'd want. and nothing to install on a desktop or mobile device, just open your browser

Comment: Thanks, sounds good! Am looking into APEX now. Not seen before, but looks like it would do the job!